# When glIsTexture is useful

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is the example opengl commands sequence:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
std::cout << (int)glIsTexture(texId) << std::endl; //0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
std::cout << (int)glIsTexture(texId) << std::endl; //1
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 
             0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.accessPixels()); //when data == 0 glIsTexture returns the same results
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
std::cout << (int)glIsTexture(texId) << std::endl; //1
glDeleteTextures(1, &texId);
std::cout << (int)glIsTexture(texId) << std::endl; //0
```

I wonder when glIsTexture function is useful ? It looks like that the main usage is checking if texture has been deleted. glIsTexture also returns false when a texture has been generated but is not bound and initialized. Do you know any other scenarios ?

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder when glIsTexture function is useful ? It looks like that the main usage is checking if texture has been deleted.

If the renderer is properly architectured, then there is no need to check if a texture has been deleted (the code would already know).

I assume the designers felt exposing the state of the texture ID could be useful for either debugging or to implement some kind of pool of textures.